# Entity Framework SQL Server Database Logging in Visual Studio / Application Insights Telemetry

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

Happy Pi Day. I am trying to make Entity Framework log its SQL Server queries to the debug window in Visual Studio. Based on some searching, including this blog post on [EF6 SQL Logging – Part 1: Simple Logging](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/), I added the following `using` statement to the controller in my MVC app:

```
using (var context = new SomeDataContext())
        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;

            SomeDataObject someData = new SomeDataObject();
            <set some app variables>

            _someDataContext.SomeData.Attach(someData);
            _someDataContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>().Single().State = Helpers.ConvertState(someData.ObjectState);
            _someDataContext.SaveChanges();

           return View(someDataViewModel);
        }
```

This is where I begin to get confused. I have two development machines. One is a Windows 7 machine running Visual Studio Professional 2015 and fails to log any SQL Server output to the debug window. However, the other, a Windows 8.1 machine running Visual Studio Community 2015, successfully outputs SQL Server transactions. The only difference that I noticed between the two IDEs is that when SQL debug works (VS Community), I have some Application Insights notifications, and when it doesn't work (VS Pro), I don't have any Application Insights notifications.

The message I'm seeing in the AI debug output that seems relevant is a class that AI is using called `SqlDataReader`.

I am using the exact same solution, including the same `ApplicationInsights.config`, in each IDE. There is no `<InstrumentationKey>` present in the config file, so I'm not sure why I get any AI messages at all.

I do have an MSDN subscription with Azure benefits, and I may have been signed in to MSDN in Visual Studio when I first created the solution.

Here's a sample of what I need to see, from the dev machine running VS Community:

```
Opened connection asynchronously at 3/14/2016 9:22:44 AM -04:00

SELECT 
[Extent1].[someDataID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[someDataName] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[someDataAddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], 

[Extent2].[otherDataID] AS [OtherID], 

[Extent3].[ExtraDataID] AS [ExtraID2], 

FROM     [dbo].[SomeData] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[OtherData] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[someDataID] = [Extent2].[OtherDataID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ExtraData] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[someDataID] = [Extent3].[ExtraDataID]



-- Executing asynchronously at 3/14/2016 9:22:44 AM -04:00

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2016-03-14T13:22:44.8155852+00:00","tags":{"ai.device.roleInstance":"xwing","ai.application.ver":"Unknown","ai.device.type":"starfighter","ai.device.id":"xwing","ai.device.oemName":"Resistance","ai.device.model":"X-wing Starfighter","ai.device.network":"spacenet","ai.device.language":"en-US","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"1.2.3.490"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"localhost\\mssqlinstance | datadb","kind":1,"value":14.1898,"dependencyKind":0,"success":true,"async":true,"dependencySource":0,"properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
-- Completed in 15 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 3/14/2016 9:22:44 AM -04:00
```

My question is essentially - how do I get Visual Studio to output Entity Framework logging - specifically SQL queries - to the debug window? Is the `using` statement from above actually doing anything, or is something inconsistent with Application Insights between the two dev machines?

Comment: I doubt it is related to AI. Most likely on one box you have 4.6 and on the other you do not so AI collects dependencies only on one box. It writes to debug even it is not fully configured so you can use VS Hub in VS 2015 and do not pollute your your prod resource with dev box telemetry.

Comment: @AnastasiaBaranchenkova As I went to check into your suggestions, I noticed that the one box no longer works with SqlDataReader. The only change to the environment is that my credentials expired in Visual Studio. I re-entered my credentials (as I had tried on the other box), yet now there is no SQL logging. It's a wild guess: perhaps my credentials were cached on the working machine, and once I re-authenticated, Azure returned an attribute that lists my Azure account as suspended - which it is for reaching credits - so I do not get the SqlDataReader class from the Azure AI library?

Comment: "Application Insights Telemetry" traces comes from Visual Studio Application Insights. It is a monitoring solution and you are not getting any classes out of it. It monitors your code, detects if you do SQL call and post it to Azure if you configured it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/